# Java jar can't access resources

Tags: java, jar, filenotfoundexception

I need to execute a jar file which uses some files located in some subfolders.

For example the directory tree can be like this:

```
jar_root/
├── executable.jar
├── folder1/
│    └── required_file1.txt
│
├── folder2/
│    └── required_file2.txt
│
├── other_folder/
│   └── ...
└── other_file.txt
```

In this example `executable.jar` needs to access `required_file1` and `required_file2`.

I need to execute the jar from another directory, so I tried this command:

```
java -cp /path/to/jar_root/ -jar /path/to/jar_root/executable.jar <options>
```

But what I got is a `FileNotFoundException` on `required_file1` (I guess the same `Exception` will be raised for `required_file2`)

How can I make the jar work?

Note that I **cannot** modify the jar, so I can't use `getResourceAsStream`, as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010487/cant-access-resources-in-executable-jar) (and other) answer(s).

Comment: How the file is loaded?

Comment: I guess it is something like `File file = new File("folder1", "required_file1")`

Comment: Then you **don't** need to set the classpath. You need to set the **current working directory!** For example `cd jar_root && java -jar ...`. In the future, access resources correctly to avoid this pain.

Comment: I feel stupid now :) unluckily I have been given this jar from third party and I need to use it as it is

Comment: You should not guess. You should know how it is loaded.

Comment: I `baksmali`d it and actually it is `new File(folder1, "required_file1")`. @BoristheSpider's answer is right!

Comment: Either the person who wrote this code is incompetent or you should be able to set `folder1` - perhaps via a commandline option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the code in the jar tries to access the files. If by relative path, that can only work if you start the program from the appropriate working directory, for example:

```
cd /path/to/jar_root/ 
java -jar executable.jar <options>
```

An alternative is to reference the files by absolute path, or relative from classpath instead of filesystem path.